# PhPmyadmin MySQL Error #1018 Xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have Installed Xampp and configured MySQL and PhPmyadmin through it. BUt, when Itry creating a new User account It shows a MySQL error#1018 which says,

> Error: 1018 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANT_READ_DIR)
>
> Message: Can't read dir of '%s' (errno: %d - %s)

this Message takes me to SQL Query in the PHPmyadmin server which shows this,

```
SHOW PLUGINS SONAME LIKE '%_password_check%'
```

I am stuck with this. I have tried different things but In vain. I will appreciate help regarding this Issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating user account with phpmyadmin or command line

Comment: I got same issue when create user account via phpmyadmin. The error message show that 'no such file or directory xampp\mysql\lib\plugin'.

Comment: For more information: the issue appears in xampp-win32-7.1.1-0-VC14-installer

Answer (score 94):

If you installed XAMPP in the default folder `C:\xampp` go and manually create the folder `C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin` in Explorer. This should fix the user creation issue.

Answer (score 2):

This error is showing that you can not read in this directory. Please check [this on mysql site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_cant_read_dir)

Normally it happens when you do not have rights on the folder, easiest is that you should give full control to "Everyone" group. Just right click on folder and in security tab "edit" and select "Everyone group" and in the lower window give check on  Full control.

Comment: You can also try start XAMPP  run as "administrator"